# Adjusting MySQL ranking query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a list of rankings from a table of matches that I have. Each line in the `matches` table represents a match that was played and includes a winner and a loser. The ranking should be based on how many wins a particular player has accrued. I currently have a query that ranks players based on wins, but it excludes players with 0 wins.

How can I adjust my query so that players with 0 wins are included in the result? Can I take losses into account so that players with 0 wins are ranked based on # of losses?

All pertinent info is below. Thank you.

`matches` table:

```
winner   |   loser   |    winner_score   |   loser_score
--------------------------------------------------------
Jason    |   Alex    |         15        |       13
Bill     |   Jason   |         14        |       11
Alex     |   Bill    |         12        |        6
Jason    |   Scott   |         13        |        8
```

my current query:

```
SELECT t1.player, 
   (SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS wins, 
                   winner   AS player 
            FROM   matches 
            GROUP  BY winner 
            ORDER  BY wins DESC) t2 
    WHERE  t2.wins > t1.wins) 
   + 1 AS rank, 
   t1.wins 
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS wins, 
           winner   AS player 
    FROM   matches 
    GROUP  BY winner 
    ORDER  BY wins DESC) t1
```

my current result:

```
player   |   rank  |    wins
------------------------------
Jason    |    1    |     2
Bill     |    2    |     1
Alex     |    2    |     1
```

my desired result:

```
player   |   rank  |    wins   |   losses
---------------------------------------------
Jason    |    1    |     2     |     1
Bill     |    2    |     1     |     1
Alex     |    2    |     1     |     1
Scott    |    3    |     0     |     1
```

Comment: Can players play each other only once?

Comment: No, they can play each other more than once

Comment: In that case, you have no PRIMARY KEY. This may be problematic.

Comment: Maybe I'm insane, but I feel like this could be more easily managed if you separated out the users from the match table and instead used their id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks complicated, but in fact it isn't :)

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2071/8/0)

---

```
select player, wins, losses, rank from (

    select ssq.*, 
    @rank := if(@prev_win = wins, @rank, @rank + 1) as rank,
    @prev_win := wins
    from (

        select
        player,
        sum(won=1) as wins,
        sum(won=0) as losses
        from (

            select
            winner as player,
            1 as won
            from
            Table1
            union all
            select
            loser as player,
            0 as won
            from 
            Table1

        ) sq
        group by player

    ) ssq
    , (select @rank := 0, @prev_win := null) var_init
    order by wins desc, wins-losses asc

) sssq
```

Comment: Those rankings look backwards to me. It's showing Scott in 1st rank with 0 wins and 1 loss.

Comment: Ooops, needed to `order by wins desc` instead of implicit `asc`. Fixed that.

Comment: I suspect that we need SUM(wins-losses) in there somewhere.

Comment: Why? It gets the same output as the desired result in the question.

Comment: @fancyPants because there are 2 users who are currently ranked second. Generally score differential would determine who is second and who is third.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Then make it `order by wins desc, wins-losses asc`. Fixed that in the query. This will get first the ones with the most wins, then the ones who have the fewest losses. It does not change the rank, since this is no requirement. Adding a second rank would be no problem.

Comment: I think the differential would come first - but it's not my tournament

Comment: I mean, it's his desired output, so you're answer is THE answer. But I know if I were Bill or Alex, I'd like to know which one of us edges the other out.

Comment: Well, I guess the OP has understood the logic, he can easily adjust it himself. If not, he can ask whatever question arises. :)

Comment: Strange. The rank part of the query works as expected when I use a DB management client, but when I do the query through a PHP script the rankings go back to being "dumb". Does this have to do with the variables?

Comment: Hard to tell, I'm no programmer, unfortunately. But I just saw, that one variable wasn't initialized. Could you have a try again?

Comment: Thanks @fancyPants, that seems to have fixed it. I think I've settled on this as my final query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2071/11 . Let me know if you see any issues or unintended consequences. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. Your query looks fine :)